# As a MA Student, there is no requirement of 'originality' - what does this mean?

Tags: research-process, masters, research-undergraduate

I do not fully understand - if not original, what will be expected of me? I am currently working on my MA thesis and realised that I just don't have any great insights and I feel I have nothing to contribute really. It really makes me sad, but I just can't find anything. I am in the Humanities, so there is almost always something to contribute if one looks long enough (or that's what I thought). But time is running out now and I feel I am just standing there empty handed.

Can I still get a good grade? What is required of me now? I don't quite understand.

Comment: You need to get with an advisor in your department and hash out your requirements. Asking here will get you general ideas as to what might be required but only your school can give you the definitive answer. Don't give up and don't feel embarrassed to ask your department what you need to do. It's their job to provide the guidance for your success but they can't help you unless you take the first step and become responsible for your own learning.

Comment: You might find these related questions helpful: 1) [What are the main differences between undergraduate, master's, and doctoral theses?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7252/what-are-the-main-differences-between-undergraduate-masters-and-doctoral-thes); 2) [What makes a Bachelor's thesis different from Master's and PhD theses?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/what-makes-a-bachelors-thesis-different-from-masters-and-phd-theses?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: thanks a lot. will it not be too embarrassing to ask now that I have realised I cannot contribute much but am already way too far into my dissertation?

Comment: There are quite a few problems with your question: 1) You are asking a lot of questions at once – please only ask one. 2) You give us hardly any information on your situation – we cannot read your mind. Did you already start a thesis? If yes, when? And how long is it supposed to take? Who made that statement? Do you have an advisor and a topic? How do master theses normally look like at your department? 3) Some of your questions are probably not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Please also take a look at [Welcome to Academia.SE!](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/1203/7734) – almost all the top answers are relevant to your question. [Why was my question put on hold for depending on individual factors?](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/3406/7734) may also give you some insight on what kind of question we can answer here.

Comment: I would spend an hour or two looking over MA theses from your department in the university library or departmental reading room or wherever they are kept, to get an idea what is appropriate regarding the kinds of topics and the depth at which the topics are investigated. While doing this you also might get an idea for your own, such as treating from Perspective B a topic someone else has already treated from Perspective A, or using a certain approach someone did with some topic as an approach for a topic you found interesting in a course you took, etc.

Comment: Your department might be requiring that you become a "subject matter expert" and not necessarily contribute anything new or original to the subject.  That's not such a simple requirement!  You'll still have to do a lot of research to reach that level and demonstrate your proficiency in and understanding of your chosen topic.  So much agreed with the perspectives above of 1) asking for advice and 2) looking at past submissions.